# find the fundamental solution using distribution

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Can anyone please explain to me step by step how to solve this question: 
Find the fundamental solution $g_k$ for the operators $ \frac{ d^k}{(dx)^k}$ on the real line such that $k=0,1,2,...$

I want this so I can understand how usually we can find the fundamental solution using distribution.

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem for small values of $k$? For $k=0$ or $k=1$ the solution is rather straightforward.

Comment: for small values, it`s Heaviside function? I want to see it all.

Comment: What do you mean by "for small values"? Write carefully the solution for $k=0$, then for $k=1$, then for $k=2$, find a pattern, make a hypothesis, then prove/disprove it.

Comment: can you please show me the case $k=2$, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us solve the question for $k=2$. We write the differential equation

$$u''=\delta_0.$$
By a standard integration exercise we can say that 
$$u'=H(x) + c_0,$$
where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function and $c_0$ is an arbitrary constant.
We integrate once again (note that in the right-hand side we have usual piece-wise continuous functions, hence usual integration can be applied) to obtain
$$u = xH(x) + c_0x + c_1,$$
where $c_1$ is another arbitrary constant.

In a general case for $k>2$ you might want to start with a polynomial $P$ of degree $k-1$ and try to find the solution of $u^{(k)}=\delta_0$ in the form $H(x)P(x)$. The polynomial is given by $k$ coefficients and you have essentially $k$ equations.

Comment: thanks a lot, that helps!